# Varying latencies in Webrtcbin Application from same host

Tags: gstreamer

I've got a basic application that does group calling:

```
webrtcbin -> video -> compositor -> etc
          -> audio -> audiomixer -> etc
```

I've noticed an interesting behaviour while monitoring end-to-end latency. My testing is done in the browser, with different tabs representing different audio/video connections. Therefore, I expect both tabs to measure the same end-to-end latency (however they don't).

The behaviour is:

1. Endpoint 1 joins, end-to-end latency is 150 ms.
2. Endpoint 2 joins, end-to-end latency for Endpoint 1 changes 300ms, while being 150 ms for Endpoint 2.

It seems like the last endpoint to join, always gets the better end-to-end latency, and the second last is always ~double.

Something else I noticed is that having an `audiomixer` affects the end-to-end latency of both endpoints, making them both over 400 ms at times.

Are there some properties that need to be set here such as `force-live`, `min-upstream-latency` or `alignment-threshold`?